# Calculate the Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I solve/prove the answers to these limits?

$\lim S(x,y) = \lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + [(\frac{1}{x} - 1)^{-\lambda} + (\frac{1}{y}-1)^{-\lambda}]^\frac{-1}{\lambda}} = \max(x,y)$

$\lim t(x,y) = \lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + [(\frac{1}{x} - 1)^{\lambda} + (\frac{1}{y}-1)^{\lambda}]^\frac{1}{\lambda}} = \min(x,y)$

Thanks...

Comment: For $(x,y)\to??$

Comment: for ${\lambda \to \infty}$. (x,y) range from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. I'm sorry, I had asked the question badly. what I want is the way to solve such limits to get to the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x>y>0$ then $$\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{x}-1\right)^{-\lambda}+\left(\dfrac{1}{y}-1\right)^{-\lambda}\right]^{\frac{-1}{\lambda}}}
 =\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{x}{x+\left[\left(1-x\right)^{-\lambda}+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}-x\right)^{-\lambda}\right]^{\frac{-1}{\lambda}}}
 =\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{x}{x+\left(1-x\right)\left[1+\left(\dfrac{1-x}{\dfrac{x}{y}-x}\right)^{\lambda}\right]^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}}}$$
$0<\alpha=\dfrac{1-x}{\dfrac{x}{y}-x}<1$
$$\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{x}{x+\left(1-x\right)\left(1+\alpha^{\lambda}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}}}=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{x}{x+\left(1-x\right)\left(1-\dfrac{\alpha^{\lambda}}{\lambda}+o\left(\alpha^{\lambda}\right)\right)}= \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{x}{1+\dfrac{\alpha^{\lambda}}{\lambda}\left(x-1\right)+o\left(\alpha^{\lambda}\right)\left(1-x\right)}=x$$
Similarly with another limits.

Comment: Thanks... I just don't get the last two lines especially when you expand $(1+a^\lambda)$ and where did $o(a^\lambda)$ come from ? could you please explain what happened there?

Comment: It's the taylor expansion around 0. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Taylor Expansion was something out of my knowledge... Guess I have to start learning it thoroughly... Thanks for your answer... I'm gonna check it... but... do you know any simpler approaches (without the Taylor Expansion) to solve limits like this? I was just wondering... Thanks again.